# Mp3 audio sequencer and mixer in C#

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, mixer

I want to create a *very* simple audio sequencer in C# that would work mostly with MP3 files or optionally any other compressed format, like Ogg or FLAC. Not just WAV.

1. User arranges audio files into a grid with multiple channels/tracks (i.e. multiple audio files playing simultaneously)
2. The whole mix (all audio files in the grid) can then be played from and paused at any moment
3. Variable volume for each channel/track. This, I suppose, could also be used to create fade in/out functionality
4. Export the whole mix into an audio file (can be WAV or anything)

I don't need any equalizers or effects beyond volume. It all sounds pretty simple to me, but I have absolutely no idea where to start with this. I've never worked with audio, so where do I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) seems like a better choice. It is open source and free.

Bonus: [VST.NET](http://vstnet.codeplex.com/) to make a VST host.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Bass.Net audio library. It supports playback of all the formats you mention and many more. It has a *lot* of functionality including multichannel mixing.

http://www.un4seen.com/

Comment: I've tried it and it looks good, but it has an annoying nag screen at startup. Is that a required part of the free version?

Comment: @FutureMillennium I have a licensed version, but as far as I can tell you have the option of getting a free license key for non-commercial use when you install it. Please see the bottom of this page for obtaining a key: http://www.neoaxisgroup.com/wiki/Tutorials/MP3Terminal/Page1, and how to apply the key: http://www.neoaxisgroup.com/wiki/Tutorials/MP3Terminal/Page2.